# HTML+CSS: combining <UL>/<OL> and faux-tabular format

Tags: html, css, hierarchical, tabular

I have a hierarchical table I want to display in HTML. The `<ul>` and `<ol>` tags work great for the hierarchical part of things, but I want to have 2 or 3 columns total where the leftmost column is indented hierarchically, e.g.

- foo

  - foo1
  - foo2

    - foo2a
  - foo3

    - foo3a
    - foo3b
- bar

  - bar1

    - bar1a
    - bar1b
  - bar2

but I also want each item to have some corresponding information on a column on the right.

How can I do this with HTML and CSS?

Comment: What kind of information will be in this 'column on the right'?

Answer (score 6):

With a table.

> but I also want each item to have some corresponding information on a column on the right.

That is tabular information.

Otherwise, you might be able to use `<ol>`/`<ul>` and make each element a [`<dl>` (definition list)](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_dl.asp), styled in such a way to make it look tabular, for example by floating every `<dd>` to the right.

```
<ol>
  <li>
    <dl>
      <dt>element 1</dt>
      <dd>corresponding information 1.1</dd>
      <dd>corresponding information 1.2</dd>
    </dl>
  </li>
  <li>
    <dl>
      <dt>element 2</dt>
      <dd>corresponding information 2.1</dd>
    </dl>
  </li>
<ol>
```